# CodeIgniter Sql syntax not working

Tags: codeigniter

Okay here i am, be direct i need some advice

so here i have some code igniter problem with "Database", this is the code

```
    $as="&amp;";
    $string1="title=";
    $a= $this->input->post('title');
    $string2="category=";
    $b= $this->input->post('category');
    $string3="length_comparison=";
    $c= $this->input->post('length_comparison');
    $string4="length=";
    $d= $this->input->post('length');


    $combine=$string1.$a.$as.$string2.$b.$as.$string3.$c.$as.$string4.$d;


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ci_query');
    $this->db->where('ci_query.query_string',$combine);             
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $rows=$query->result();
    $count=0;

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $count=$count+1;
        $query_id = $row->id;
    }

    if($count==0)
    {
        $query_id = $this->input->save_query($query_array);
    }


    redirect("films/display/$query_id");
```

Here is the logic

```
 1. i got an input from a search form  tittle,category,length_comparison,and length.
 2. first case these logic will save all those input into a column in a table, all in 1 column, if there is no same parameter
"tittle,category,length_comparison,and length" in the table.
 3. but if there is any same parameter it will not insert to the table, and just redirect to the page i choose
 4. from the table we got the id and display instead of using long query string. display the search result.
```

My problem :
i've done the coding and it's work perfectly in my computer/pc. but when i use my laptop it's just doesn't work, anyone can give me some advice ? or my coding? or ci version? or what?

Update :

i think that is not the problem since i've override the lib, so i have this to use that function

```
function save_query($query_array) {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->db->insert('search', array('query_string' => http_build_query($query_array)));

    return $CI->db->insert_id();
}

function load_query($query_id) {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $rows = $CI->db->get_where('search', array('id' => $query_id))->result();
    if (isset($rows[0])) {
        parse_str($rows[0]->query_string, $_GET);       
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is the generated sql query is the same in both environments? Use `$this->db->last_query();` to get it. I guess php/mysql versions and configurations are not exact duplicates between the two environments.

Comment: Where you count your results, there is a built-in method in CI that you can use for that. `$this->db->count_all_results();`

Comment: Is it throwing any errors or warnings?

Comment: no error no warning, i just thought it was the php/mysql version. not sure tough

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
if($count==0)
{
    $this->db->insert('ci_query', array('query_string' => $combine));
    $query_id = $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

That way you are inserting the correct data, and you are reading the correct ID from the database.

Comment: i think that's not it sean, really dunno what's wrong here T_T, this code work perfectly in my computer just when i tried to test in my friend it's suddenly not working. May the php version or some technical cause this?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?